# when using javascript how would i create an if statement for a selected option

Tags: php, javascript

I am new to javascript however I am trying to create a if else statement with the following options.

```
<select name="remote_server" class="required">
<option></option>
<option value="1" <?php if($remote=="1") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Yes</option>
<option value="0" <?php if($remote=="0") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>No</option>
</select>
```

I am looking to do something like

```
if remote_server = 1 then 
    document.getElementByName("hostname").disabled = true;
else 
    nothing
```

EDIT 1:

I am now trying the following with no success

```
var e = document.getElementsByName("remote_server");
var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

if ( strUser == 0 ) {
    document.getElementsByName("ftp_hostname").disabled = true;
}
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: ive only tried some basic code ive found online to test it

var remote_server = document.getElementByName("remote_server");
var selection = remote_server.options[remote_server.selectedIndex].value;

if (selection == "1") {
    alert("selected!");
}

Comment: My code is **exactly** the same as yours. Then what's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getElementsByName` returns an array of elements, so if you want the first element named "remote_server", you should use `document.getElementsByName("remote_server")[0]`.

Similarly, you'll want to use `document.getElementsByName("ftp_hostname")[0].disabled`.